# On Java 9 why is the output from System.getenv() incomplete in jshell?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, java-9, jshell

I'm using Windows 10 and running the version of Java 9 released by Oracle yesterday.

If I open a **jshell** and enter **System.out.println(System.getenv())** the output is as expected, as shown in the lower portion of the screen shot below.

However, if I simply enter **System.getenv()** there is a big chunk of data missing from the middle of the output. See the initial portion of the screen shot below. This appears to be a feature of **jshell** since in the screen shot below the ellipsis ("**...**") in the output from **System.getenv()** (within the second box with hand drawn yellow edges) exactly corresponds to the missing data.

The end portion for the environment variable **CommonProgramFiles** is missing, as is the start of the environment variable **SPRING_HOME**, and there are several other environment variables such as **Path** which are not shown at all.

[image]

(Some information in the screen shot has been blurred for privacy.)

Does anyone else see the same thing (or not), and does anyone have suggestions on why **jshell** is doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JShell does truncate some string results that are printed in the REPL.  It doesn't effect the printing to the console however.

We can see the same thing happening running this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
List<Integer> x = IntStream.range(0,3000).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
x
```

We will see the same truncation with the ellipsis occur in that output.

If we print the result:

```
System.out.println(x);
```

we don't see this.

---

This is user configurable.  For example, we can create a custom format mode that allows up to 40,000 characters (an excessively high number which we will likely not encounter, so no truncation occurs).

```
/set mode mine normal -command
/set truncation mine 40000
/set feedback mine
```

This creates a new feedback mode called **mine** which inherits from the built in mode **normal**<sup>†</sup> (there are apparently *a lot* of options, so we inherit from another mode so that we don't have to worry about setting everything).  See `/help /set mode` for details.

The second command sets the truncation to 40000 characters.  It is possible to configure this so that the truncation depends on what sort of thing is displayed.  See `/help /set truncation` for details.

Finally, the last command here switches to this feedback mode.  Now, any thing displayed in the console will no longer be truncated unless it exceeds 40,000 characters.

[This link](http://java.genedavis.com/2016/06/jshell-commands.html) along with the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm#JSWOR-GUID-C337353B-074A-431C-993F-60C226163F00) and the help commands above helped with figuring this out in order to write this answer.

---

<sup>†</sup> The **normal** mode shows up to 1,000 characters before truncation.  Use `/set truncation` by itself to display the various truncation settings or `/set truncation normal` to display the settings for **normal** mode.

Comment: Ah, from your link it seems you can configure it using "/set truncation <mode> <length> <selector> ...". Yet I still can't figure out exactly what to specify in jshell to prevent lengthy output being truncated...

Comment: @skomisa I have edited the answer so that it actually shows how to adjust the truncation.  I don't think that it is possible to prevent it altogether, but this answer shows how to set the displayed number of characters extremely high.

Comment: Your configuration commands worked perfectly for me. I also found a link which explains the positioning of the ellipsis if the output is truncated: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166637